# Google Vertex UI does not show correct kernel name

Tags: kernel, conda, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

All created kernels with the conda environment are named in the same way.

[UI kernels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvtH5.png)

The display-name seems to be correct, rebooting does not help as well.

[kernel.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSV0w.png)

I dont have such kind of issue in the jupyterhub.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Jupyter kernel using ipykernel, the kernel specification is saved to a default location, typically in your user directory. However, you can specify a different location using the `--prefix` option when installing the kernel. Try using location for default Python 3 kernel and check if you see same behavior.

```
jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  myenv_kernel    /opt/conda/share/jupyter/kernels/myenv_kernel
  python3         /opt/conda/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Try installing kernels in this location:

```
/opt/conda/share/jupyter/kernels/
```

This is my `kernel.json`

```
more /opt/conda/share/jupyter/kernels/myenv_kernel/kernel.json 
{
 "argv": [
  "/opt/conda/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "My Custom Environment",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

[image]